# What is wrong with this weight painting?

Tags: weight-painting

Before I did anything, the top part of the boot was green and looked to have a hole. Now I have manged to make it look better but it doesn't quite deform right.

I tried using rigify but I had no success so I made my own rig which also hasn't really helped.

Perhaps if I add a knee help bone could that fix the issue?

[image: When I used automatic weights the top part of the boot (which is now red) was green and quite badly deformed. I've managed to make it normal but for some reason the top part of the boot wont bend around the knee correctly]

[image: the top part of the boot doesn't properly bend round the knee right. I've tried data transferring but it hasn't worked]png

Comment: Have you turned on Auto-Normalize in your weight painting options? It looks like the are more weights on other bones..

Comment: @Leander that has fixed the issue.